# Indentation error while creating a package

Tags: python, module, package, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a simple package like this:

```
areas
    __init__.py
    circunferencia.py
    rectangulo.py
```

I saved this file as areas.py. circunferencia.py cointains this:

```
PI=3.1415
def area(r):
    return PI*r**2
```

And rectangulo:

```
def area(a):
    return a*a
```

I create another .py:

```
import areas
print(areas.circunferencia.area(3))
print(areas.rectangulo.area(2))
```

And when I try to run my package it gives me this error

```
    __init__.py
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the code, can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: areas should be a folder/directory on your system, not a file, with in it your python files (\_\_init\_\_.py,   circunferencia.py   rectangulo.py)

Comment: Wait, is that first bit with `areas` and `__init__.py` text from an actual file you're trying to run? The error message looks like you're trying to actually execute that. That's what your directory structure should look like, not text you should actually put in a `.py` file.

Comment: Packages are defined by directory structure, into the subdirectories go `__init__.py` files and your `whatever.py` file that implements the functions. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Thanks, so I saved it in a folder called 'areas' in \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages and I put there circunferencia.py and rectangulo.py. The file that I called areas.py should be called __init__.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a package. On your current project directory for example (`/home/jack/pyproject`) you can create a folder called `area` then put all the python files inside the folder, with file `__init__.py` inside of it so you can import the package when working on (`/home/jack/pyproject`).

If you want to import the package from another directory, then you can add the path of `/home/jack/pyproject` into the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
therefore you do not need to add it in your site-package.